# Rails: friendly_id & globalize not checking translation tables for conflicts

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, friendly-id, globalize3

I'm using **friendly_id (4.10.1)** and **globalize (3.0.0)** in my Rails 3.2.14 app:

```
# globalize3
translates :title, :slug

# friendly_id    
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :globalize]
```

When I save my inputs, friendly_id checks for slug collisions:

```
SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE
("slug" = 'my-title' OR "slug" LIKE 'my-title--%') AND (id <> 1)
ORDER BY LENGTH("slug") DESC, "slug" DESC LIMIT 1
```

Friendly_id should use the translation table `page_translations` for this, because the entry in the original table `pages` is kinda random when you use multiple locales.

And that's the problem: friendly_id only recognizes slug collisions for one language/locale.

Does anyone have an idea how to alter the query for full **globalize** support? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Thanks for noticing this. Can you post an issue about this on the [globalize github repository](https://github.com/globalize/globalize)?